# Droid DNA Not Supported in Android Device List

Tags: android

Why is my application shown as unsupported device for the new HTC Droid DNA, my manifest is This application is only available to devices with these features, as defined in your application manifest. Screen densities: NORMAL,LDPI NORMAL,XHDPI NORMAL,HDPI NORMAL,MDPI SMALL,LDPI SMALL,XHDPI SMALL,HDPI SMALL,MDPI XLARGE,LDPI XLARGE,XHDPI XLARGE,HDPI XLARGE,MDPI LARGE,LDPI LARGE,XHDPI LARGE,HDPI LARGE,MDPI LARGE,TVDPI Required device features
android.hardware.screen.portrait android.hardware.touchscreen android.hardware.wifi This application is available to over 2230 devices.

Answer (score 1):

My first answer actually lowered the number of supported devices this is the correct answer, increased my number of supported devices from 2217 to 2495

```
 <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! You have no idea how much I have searched for a solution! Did you try it out manually or did you find the value somewhere else? I was almost about to make a script that would brute force Google Play... It feels so strange that there is no comprehensive list of all available values anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, it me so long to answer you, I have not been back to this post. I honestly got the answer from a conversation with a Android Developer friend who works in Nashville. Didn't ask him where he got just happy it works!

Answer (score 0):

ATI texture compression. Available on devices running Adreno GPU, including HTC Nexus One, Droid Incredible, EVO, and others. For widest compatibility, devices may also declare a  element with the descriptor GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc. Droid DNA uses Adreno GPU so you should add to manifest.

```
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, to ensure you have a supported device and you are looking for the correct device name, you can refer to Google Play's complete list of known devices: 
http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1727131